# Align ShareThis buttons with header in Bootstrap 4

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

How can I vertically align ShareThis buttons with header in Bootstrap 4?

[image]

```
  <h1>Chat <span class="pull-right"><span class='st_facebook_hcount' displayText='Facebook'></span><span class='st_twitter_hcount' displayText='Tweet'></span></span></h1>
```

Comment: you mean these facebook and tweet buttons..??

Comment: Yes it's ShareThis site

Comment: It is already vertically align

Comment: try to use "row" class of div...

Comment: @ketan no it's not. The share button starts at the bottom of the t in Chat. That's not aligned

Comment: I didn't see any share button your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are after a way to vertically align the middle of two:

```css
h1{vertical-align: middle;}
h1 .pull-right{display:inline-block;font-size:10px;vertical-align: middle;}
```

```html
<h1>Chat <span class="pull-right"><span class='st_facebook_hcount' displayText='Facebook'>Facebook</span><span class='st_twitter_hcount' displayText='Tweet'>Tweeter</span></span></h1>
```

but a better approach would be to use flex:

```css
h1{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}
.pull-right{
  font-size: 10px;
}
```

```html
<h1><span>Chat</span><span class="pull-right"><span class='st_facebook_hcount' displayText='Facebook'>Facebook</span><span class='st_twitter_hcount' displayText='Tweet'>Tweeter</span></span></h1>
```